# Getting a mobile site to display as a desktop site, mine isn't, any ideas?

Tags: css, header, web, resize

Please take into consideration I am pretty new to programming and only know basic things!

Currently, the header on my shop has not got a width set and works fine on the desktop site > feel free to visit to view www.Part-Box.com

However, when the site is loaded on a mobile device or a tablet, the view changes and the header is cut off > you can test this by resizing the browser on a pc. Basically I want the mobile version and desktop version to be exactly the same. There is currently a zoom on the mobile version and half of the header gets cut off.

I've tried setting the header to have a width of 100% in the css which works but completley rearranges everything in the header, can anyone help? thanks guys.

(it would be a lot easier to understand with pictures sorry)

**Solution found** by removing a line of code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Please post relevant code here.

Comment: This is all the header css code... I didn't create this (new apprentice)

Comment: #header ul{
 margin:0;
 padding: 9px 0 0 0;
}

#header li{
 display:inline;
 padding-left: 6px;
}

#header a{
 color:#2b2b2b;
 font-weight:normal;
}

#header a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
}

Comment: Let me rephrase: please [**edit your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29010986/edit) and post relevant code there.

Comment: I can see that all the containers have a fixed width of  `1000px` so, I see a normal behavior

Comment: I believe you meant to reference `#hotline` from your CSS and not `#header`. `#header` does not have a width set and by default has `width: 100%` as it is a block level element. So setting `width: 100%` doesn't change anything. In both of the situations you've described, setting a set width or a percentage width, you are seeing expected behavior. What do you expect to happen? Have everything in the header scale down? You need to apply additional styling for when the elements re-arrange so they do so in a pleasant way. You can do that via media queries.

Comment: Apologies hungerstar (im a noob) - The outcome I want is for the desktop version and the mobile version to be exactly the same

Comment: So you want the browser to zoom out on the webpage?

Comment: Yes, and for the hotline/header to display properly > thanks for helping so far, appreciate it

Comment: In that case I believe you need to remove the meta tag that is meant for responsive design websites - which yours is not. This is the meta tag you're looking for: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`. Without it the browser should zoom out when loaded on smaller screen devices. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: Hungerstar> THANKS! I removed the meta tags and it loads fine on a mobile device now. It's very slightly cut off at the end but thanks for your help.

Comment: @s.poole 1) there's not a whole lot you can do about that. Adjusting the height of various page elements won't fix it either as the height of various mobile screens varies wildly. The simplest way to see this in action is to view the page in portrait mode vs landscape mode. 2) Please update your question pointing out how you wanted the page to look when on smaller screens so those that come across this question don't have to dig through our comments. I myself will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Per comments above:** the OP wanted their website to look the same on desktop and mobile. That is, no layout re-ordering, re-sizing or re-styling.

To do what you want we need the mobile browser to zoom out so the whole page can be seen. This happens to be what mobile browsers do by default.

The reason this is not happening for you is because you are using a `meta` tag that is widely used for Responsive Web Design layouts:

> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Remove that tag from the page and you should see the results you are looking for.

***I realize that this isn't an ideal user experience choice but this is what the OP asked for.*

Comment: Thanks for your help. Although its not ideal user experience, my website has over 100+000 products listed... and will need to be re-designed from scratch for the best mobile friendly user experience.

Comment: @s.poole I totally understand that. I'm attempting to proactively respond to the eventual comment(s) by others saying as much. Glad I could help out!